# How to get number of the users registered in this month in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-datatables

Pls help me
I wnat to get number of the Users registered in this week
and number of the Users registered in this month

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```php
$lastWeekUsersCount = \App\Models\User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addWeeks(-1))->count();
$lastMonthUsersCount = \App\Models\User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonths(-1))->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

$lastWeekUsersCount = User::whereDate('created_at', '>=',Carbon::now()->addWeeks(-1))->count();

$lastMonthUsersCount = User::whereDate('created_at', '>=',Carbon::now()->addMonths(-1))->count();
```